# Adding previous lines to current line unless pattern is found in unix shell script

Tags: unix

I am facing an issue while adding previous lines to current line for a pattern. I have a 43 MB file in unix. The snippet is shown below:

```
AAA7034  new value and a old value

A

78698 new line and old value

BCA0987 old value and new value

new value
```

What I want is :

```
AAA7034 new value and a old value A 78698 new line and old value

BCA0987 old value and new value new value
```

Means I have add all the the lines till next pattern is found ( first pattern is : AAA and next pattern is : BCA )

because of high size of files..not sure if awk/sed shall work. Any bash script is appreciated.

Comment: Describe the pattern you are looking for - three letters at the beginning of the line ?

Comment: Pattern is AAA, BCA.. its not like 3 letters but 2 patterns AAA, BCA. It can have 4 four letters as well.

Comment: Do you know ALL patterns that exist or do you want to FIND patterns matching some rule?

Comment: I know All the patterns that exist. For example patter shall be like : AAA, BCS , BABA, BCA. That's why . Instead of rule it shall be like: if the line starts with any of these then the next all the lines shall be added to that line until the above matching pattern found.

Comment: Your description is meaningless.  Are 'AAA', 'BCS', 'BABA', and 'BCA' the only patterns you care about?  Or do you mean that you want to match any line that starts with a string of at least 3 uppercase letters?  Would 'A7A' count as a pattern?  Does 'ABCDE' count as a pattern, or is 5 letters too many?  What will you do with the line 'ABC7e BCDE ABC FED'?  Computers require precision.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine all patterns and perform a regex match. Try something like this (it is just a scratch, you should trim the output if you need):

```
#!/bin/bash
patterns="^(AAA|BCS|BABA|BCA)"
file="$1"
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ "$line" =~ $patterns ]] ; then 
        echo # prints new line
    fi
    echo -n $line " " # prints the line itself and a space as a separator
done < "$file"
```

You can redirect the output to a file, of course.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear precisely what you want.  You've stated that you want to match the patterns 'AAA' and 'BCA', and later expanded that to "patter shall be like: AAA, BCS, BABA, BCA".  I don't know if that means that you only want to match 'AAA', 'BCA', 'AAA, 'BCS, 'BABA', and 'BCA, or  if you want to match 3 or 4 characters strings containing only 'A', B', 'C', and 'S', but it sounds like you are just looking for:

```
awk '/[A-Z]{3,4}/{printf "\n"} { printf "%s ", $0} END {printf "\n"}' input-file
```

Change the pattern as needed when your requirements are made more precise.

Based on the comment, it is trivial to convert any awk program to perl.  Here is (basically) the output of `a2p` on the above awk script, with changes to reflect the stated pattern:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    if (/AAA|BCA|BCS|BABA/) {
        printf "\n";
    }
    printf '%s ', $_;
}
printf "\n";
```

You can simplify that a bit:

```
perl -pe 'chomp; printf "\n" if /AAA|BCA|BCS|BABA/; printf "%s ", $_' input-file; echo
```

Comment: let me explain: let say: my lines are : AAA7685 A

Comment: My pattern is AAA|BCA|BCS|BABA. Means if the line starts with the patterns, then the next line shall add to previous line until any of the above pattern is found.  I tried with awk but faced awk: Input line cannot be longer than 3,000 bytes as I said the lines are big and more than 3000 bytes. I cannot use gawk and nawk as those cannot be installed. any idea what else i can do. Any perl command or python?

Comment: @George Converting awk to perl is pretty trivial.  There's a nice tool that does it for you!  `a2p` is the awk to perl translator.